# Required field validator not visible in panel after async call

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

I've got a strange situation where an asp.net validation control is not being rendered to the page. The control lives inside an initially hidden asp.net panel which gets made visible based on the results of an `async` call.

Here is the panel:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlGasReading" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="form-group clearfix">
    <asp:Label ID="lblFinalGasReading" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtFinalGasReading" Text="Final Gas Reading" />
    <flow:HelpText runat="server" ID="ucFinalGasReadingHelpText" HelpTextKey="ChangeOfTenancy-FinalGasReading" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFinalGasReading" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valFinalGasReading" ControlToValidate="txtFinalGasReading" ErrorMessage="Final Gas Reading is required." ValidationGroup="COTForm" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="animate-error" />
</asp:Panel>
```

The validation control in question is called `valFinalGasReading`.

Here is the async call, snipped to the relevant parts:

```
private async Task ConfigureAlreadyMovedMeterReadingFields()
{
    string accountId = _userContext.CurrentAccount.Id;

    var metersResponse = await _accountService.GetMetersForAccountAsync(accountId);

    if (metersResponse.IsSuccess)
    {
        var meters = metersResponse.ResponseContent.Meters;

        if (meters.Any())
        {
            if (meters.Any(x => x.Utility == MeterUtilityType.Gas))
            {
                pnlGasReading.Visible = true;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

This is being called in the Page load event by:

```
Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(ConfigureAlreadyMovedMeterReadingFields));
```

Since this call is essentially 'fire and forget' and does not wait before proceeding with the rest of the page execution I believe the page load is finishing before the async method call can complete.

I'm finding that the fields inside of the panel are all showing up e.g label, textbox, help text control, however the required field validator does not.

Is there something special about the required field validator that means it needs to be on the page before page load completes? Is there a way of awaiting the results of this call so that we don't end up with this race condition?

I've tried marking the Page load `async` e.g:

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

And then awaiting the result, but this throws an error :

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle.

Comment: The problem with async is that it can complete later that the life cycle of the page. That means the complete html has already been rendered and send to the browser by the time the task completes. So changing the visibility does not work.

Comment: @VDWWD - Yeah, i did suspect that the page was loading before the async call came back. That doesn't explain why some controls are loaded such as Textbox/Label etc... yet the required field validator is not, there must be something special about the RFV that requires it be visible before the page load/pre render event. I've added an answer to this with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reading the docs on [Page.RegisterAsyncTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.executeregisteredasynctasks(v=vs.110).aspx) it states that tasks registered with `Page.RegisterAsyncTask` will be run in the page `PreRender` event:

> The ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks method is automatically called at the point in the page processing when any registered asynchronous tasks, if they exist, are invoked for a non-asynchronous page. This automatic call to ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks occurs just before the PreRenderComplete event.

Which is too late in the page lifecycle. You can run any queued async tasks immediately through `Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks` which seems to fix my problem however it doesn't explain why some controls inside the panel still worked `TextBox`/`Label` for example were shown fine. There must be something special going on with `RequiredFieldValidators` which requires them to be visible before the `PageLoad` event completes.